# Parsing html tags JSON Angular

Tags: json, parsing, angularjs

I'm receiving the following JSON from my server, in reality the reviews array is filled with 20+ reviews but here I am only presenting one...

```
{
    "reviews": [
        "<br>We have found 20 reviews on external websites <br>Review 1 bla bla<br>Review 2 bla bla<br>The original reviews page: <a href=\"http://www.edmunds.com/honda/civic/2013/consumer-reviews.html\">2013 Honda Civic Consumer Reviews</a><br>"            
    ]}
```

I would like to parse the data and present it in the view using the html tags that are provided in the JSON.
So the end result in the view would look like -

```
We have found 20 reviews in external websites
Review 1 bla bla
Review 2 bla bla
The original reviews page: 
2013 Honda Civic Consumer Reviews(link)
```

What is the correct way to go about doing this process in Angular?

Thanks ahead,
Gidon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the documentation here to parse html tags - 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize